# How to remove all classes with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some up/down buttons that increase/decrease the size of the selected text by adding a class to the containing element, like

```js
<span class="font20">Some text</span>
```

The `font20` class sets `font-size:20px`, `font21` sets `font-size: 21`, etc.

I have another button "Clear Formatting" that needs to remove any classes I added. I could go through and see if `font20` is applied and remove it if it is. If not, see if `font21` is applied and remove it if it is, etc. and go through 50 or so possibilities. But what I'd rather do is something like

```js
jQuery('selector').removeClass("*");
```

That is, remove all classes that may have been added. 
The `removeClass("*")` above doesn't seem to work.  Is there another way to remove all the classes applied to a selector, using jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: `removeClass("*")` would try to remove a class with name `*`. And it almost looks like you didn't read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/): *"If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed."*

Comment: Use a wildcard selector `$("class*=font")`

Comment: Anthony, Could you say a few words about this `$("class*=font")` structure, or point me to some documentation? Thanks. –  Steve

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just use

```js
jQuery('selector').removeClass();
```

to remove all the classes.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

> If a class name is included as a parameter, then only that class will be removed from the set of matched elements. If no class names are specified in the parameter, all classes will be removed.

So simply using:

```
$('#whatever').removeClass();
```

will remove all classes from `#whatever`.

Comment: That is not what OP wants.

Comment: Reread the question.  You're right, it's not the whole solution, but it will remove all classes as per the question.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
selector$.attr("class", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

When I want to retain a base class and remove any dynamically added classes I'll do something like the following.

I'll add a data attribute on the element with the default classes.

```
<span class="default dynamic" data-class="default">Text</span>
```

Then, to reset it I'll simply apply the `data-class` element to the `class`.

```
var defaultClass = $('span').attr('data-class');
$('span').attr('class', defaultClass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling removeClass with no parameters will remove all of the item's classes.

```
$("span").removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only remove classes added via your buttons, then jQuery allows you to remove several (space separated) classes in 1 call:

```
selector$.removeClass("font1 font2 font3 fontx");
```

If you are happy removing all the classes regardless of whether you added them via your formatting buttons you could do:

```
selector$.removeClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code with an example which will show you how you can solve this issue. I'm assuming that you only want to remove the classes matching a specific format (namely the font## format).

You can add a function to jQuery's object, which will be callable on a jQuery object. This function then will check for a list of classes the element contains and match each one of them against your pattern.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.removeMatchingClasses = function(expression) {
        var $element    = $(this);
        var classString = $element.attr('class');
        if(classString !== undefined) {
            $(classString.split(' ')).each(function() {
                var str = (this + '');
                if(str.match(expression)) {
                    $element.removeClass(str);
                }
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span").each(function() {
        // remove all classes from this element matching font(number)
        $(this).removeMatchingClasses(/^font([0-9]+)$/);
    });
});
```

This code will preserve all the non-matching classes of an element, and only remove the matching ones.

Some references:

- https://api.jquery.com/attr/ (used to determine the classes)
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp (used to match the classes with a pattern)

Comment: Thanks.  You're solving a problem that's way more complicated than the one I have now, but I'll save a reference to this article for later.